# Run java class from maven if parameter is specified

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I'm trying to run a java class which populates my database with dummy data. In eclipse I do it just by right clicking and running as java program. The problem is I'd like make jenkins do it... obvious solution would be running a class using maven as it would put everything needed on the classpath.

I have tried http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ like this:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>populatedb</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>populatedb</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.DatasetReader</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

But it gives me `ClassNotFound on com.example.DatasetReader` before the project is even built. I use this command:

```
mvn clean install exec:java -Dpopulatedb -Dclasspath -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.DatasetReader"
```

I think it have to do something with execution phase... but there is nothing like post-install...

Thanks!

Comment: Is `DatasetReader` by any chance a "test" class (i.e. is it under `src/test/java`)?

Comment: Could you please add your error log?

Comment: As an aside your command will (when successful) cause the exec-maven-plugin to be run twice. Once because you have activated the profile, and once because you explicitly call the `exec:java` goal. Calling `mvn clean install -Dpopulatedb` should be enough to have the exec-maven-plugin to be run as configured in the profile in your pom.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is to do with the classpath that is used by the exec-maven-plugin. By default the exec-maven-plugin uses the `runtime` classpath. I presume that your `DatasetReader` class is a test class so is only available on the `test` classpath.

To pass a different classpath to the exec-maven-plugin you use the [`classpathScope` property](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#classpathScope).

So you would use `<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>` in your pom to have the plugin run with the test classpath.

So you would simply need to modify your POM to be as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope> <!-- this is the extra config -->
        <mainClass>com.example.DatasetReader</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: DatasetReader is located in src/main/java. It does not refer to anything related with tests. But this will certainly be useful for someone who has it in there! Thank you :)

Comment: I would further improve this by suggesting you put the '<plugin/>` inside a `<profile/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try without additional phases:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.DatasetReader"
```

or adding classpath scope from runtime:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.DatasetReader" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime
```

Comment: Do you have valid jar?